# SerializationException: Start of structure or map found where not expected in AWS Cognito GlobalSignOut function

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I'm working on a project where I need to implement user logout functionality using AWS Cognito. I'm using the '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider' library (version 3.329.0) in my Node.js application.

I have the following 'logoutUser' method in my Cognito service:

```
async logoutUser(accessToken: string): Promise<GlobalSignOutCommandOutput> {
  const param: GlobalSignOutCommandInput = {
    AccessToken: accessToken, // required
  };
  try {
    return this.cognitoIdentityProvider.globalSignOut(param);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.name === 'InvalidParameterException') {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        'Invalid parameters provided for user logout.',
      );
    } else if (error.name === 'NotAuthorizedException') {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'User not authorized to perform this operation.',
      );
    } else {
      throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
        'Failed to log out user. Please try again later.',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to invoke the 'globalSignOut' method with the provided access token, I receive the following error:

```
   at CognitoService.logoutUser (C:\Users\yocha\billy\billyUp_test\auth-service\src\cognito\cognito.service.ts:401:14) {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'a6d4e906-bb5c-4b7a-b62f-8ca4263f753b',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  __type: 'SerializationException'
}
SerializationException: Start of structure or map found where not expected
```

I have verified that the access token is valid and the required parameters are provided correctly. I also ensured that I'm using the compatible version of the '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider' library.

I'm not sure what is causing this serialization error. Could someone please help me identify the issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.